# Move files not working in powershell (Source and destination same issue)

Tags: powershell

I am trying to move all the files inside a folder to folder which is one step back. Suppose I have three files in **vpa_images** folder and I want to move those files to **VPA_IMAGES** file and delete **vpa_images** folder:

[image]

I tried by using:

```
$new_path=$vpa_images+'\vpa_images'
echo $new_path
echo $vpa_images
Move-Item $new_path $vpa_images
```

I am getting issue as:

```
D:\RAW\st\Docum\2021-10-12\VPA_IMAGES\vpa_images
D:\RAW\st\Docum\2021-10-12\VPA_IMAGES
Move-Item : Source and destination path must be different.
At D:\powershwll\automationforstaples.ps1:49 char:1
+ Move-Item $new_path $vpa_images
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (D:\RAW\St...AGES\vpa_images:DirectoryInfo) [Move-Item], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MoveDirectoryItemIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MoveItemCommand
```

How can take all the files to the **VPA_IMAGES** folder?

Comment: The folder at `$new_path` is already located inside `$vpa_images`, not much to be done. You want `Get-ChildItem $new_path |Move-Item -Destination $vpa_images`

Comment: it worked put your comment properly i will tick it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The folder at `$new_path` is already located inside `$vpa_images` - which is why you receive the error you see.

You'll want:

```
Get-ChildItem $new_path |Move-Item -Destination $vpa_images
```

`Get-ChildItem` will enumerate the files/folders inside `$new_path` and `Move-Item` then moves each of them to `$vpa_images`